# Constructor doesnt set any values

Tags: java, constructor

I started a simple project, but I've encountered a problem.
Main class

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    /*
• Ask the user how many new students will be added to the database.
• The user should be prompted to enter a name and year for each student.
• The student should have a unique 5-digit id, with the first being their grade level.
• The student should have several course options to choose from.
• Each course costs $600 to enroll.
• The student should be able to check their balance and pay tuition.
• The status of the student should show their name, id, courses, and balance.
     */
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberOfStudents=0,year;
    String firstName,lastName;

    System.out.println("How many students will attend this School? ");
    //input number of students
    System.out.print("Input : ");
    numberOfStudents = input.nextInt();
    //end
    //Input name and year for every student
    Student  students [] = new Student[numberOfStudents];
    Deposit deposit [] = new Deposit[numberOfStudents];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfStudents ;i ++){
        students[i]=new Student();
        deposit[i]=new Deposit(students[i]);
        //It consumes the /n character
        input.nextLine();
        //
        System.out.print("Insert First name : ");
        firstName=input.nextLine();
        students[i].setFirstName(firstName);

        System.out.print("Insert last name : ");
        lastName=input.nextLine();
        students[i].setLastName(lastName);

        System.out.print("Input year :");
        year=input.nextInt();
        students[i].setYear(year);
        //set cash test
        students[i].setCash(1000);
        //end
    }
    for(int j = 0 ; j < numberOfStudents ; j++){
        System.out.println("Student " + j + " First name " + students[j].getFirstName() + " has " + deposit[j].getBalance());
    }

    //end


}
```

Student class

```
private String firstName,lastName;
private int year,grade,cash;
private int[] studentID = new int[5];

public Student(){

}

public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int year) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.year = year;
}

public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int year, int grade, int cash) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.year = year;
    this.grade = grade;
    this.cash=cash;
}

private int[] RandomID(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    this.studentID[0] = this.grade;
    for(int i = 1; i <= this.studentID.length-1 ; i ++ ){
        int randomNumbers = rand.nextInt(10);

        this.studentID[i] = randomNumbers;
    }
    return this.studentID;
}


public int[] getStudentID() {
    return RandomID();
}


public int getCash() {
    return cash;
}

public void setCash(int cash) {
    this.cash=cash;
}


public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public int getGrade() {
    return grade;
}

public void setGrade(int grade) {
    this.grade = grade;
}
```

Deposit class:

```
private Student student;
private int balance;

public Deposit(){

}

public Deposit(Student student){
    this.student = student;
    this.balance=student.getCash();
}

public void checkBalance(){
    System.out.println("You have " + this.student.getCash() + " on this account");
}


public Student getStudent() {
    return student;
}

public void setStudent(Student student) {
    this.student = student;
}

public int getBalance() {
    return this.balance;
}

public void setBalance(int balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}
```

When I call in Main `System.out.println(deposit[j].getBalance());`, it says it's 0, but I put it in the constructor in the Deposit class.

Shouldn't `this.balance` have a value from `student.getCash()`?
The checkBalance method in deposit gives me the value that I need when I call it in the main class student.getCash().

Comment: Your Deposit constructor is calling getCash before any of the Student fields have been initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're initializing the `Deposit` with a `Student` instance before you initialize its `cash`, so it'll be `0`. Move the initialization of the `Deposit` after you're done initializing the corresponding `Student` and you should be OK:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfStudents ;i ++){
    students[i]=new Student();
    //It consumes the /n character
    input.nextLine();
    //
    System.out.print("Insert First name : ");
    firstName=input.nextLine();
    students[i].setFirstName(firstName);

    System.out.print("Insert last name : ");
    lastName=input.nextLine();
    students[i].setLastName(lastName);

    System.out.print("Input year :");
    year=input.nextInt();
    students[i].setYear(year);
    //set cash test
    students[i].setCash(1000);
    //end

    deposit[i]=new Deposit(students[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value is being set at the time you create a `Deposit` object, which is immediately after you create a new `Student` object. At that time, the value of `cash` in the `Student` instance is zero. You don't set that until later. You could do something like:

```
public int getBalance() {
    return this.student.getCash();
}
```

Instead of setting a `balance` member once, this would call the method on the `Student` instance each time to get the updated value. I'm not saying this is the best design, but it appears to be what you expected to happen.